What is the probability of $\alpha$- quantile
I didn't understand why the $P(X \leq q_{\alpha}^- (X))=\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<1$. Please help me with this. The setup for it:
X is a real random variable and the lower $\alpha$-quantile defined by
$q_{\alpha}^- (X)= \inf \{x: P(X \leq x) \geq \alpha\}$. From the definition of quantile I understand that $P(X \leq q_{\alpha}^- (X)) \geq\alpha$. But the equality is not clear for me. Please help.

It is not actually obvious that $P(X \leq q_{\alpha}^- (X)) \geq\alpha$ from the definition of quantile. Though $q_\alpha^-(X)$ is the infimum of the set $S = {x : P(X \le x) \ge \alpha}$, in general the infimum of a set does not need to be an element of the set, and something specific to the probability setting must happen to tell us that $q_\alpha^-(X) \in S$.
